# How does extends configure the prototype chain?

Tags: javascript

```
class Foo extends Bar {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

Does `super` invoke the constructor function (aka class) `Bar`?

Is `Bar.prototype` configured to be the prototype property of `Foo`?

In class methods (and literal methods) `super` can be used as a reference to the instance of `Bar` (I think). Can it be used in the same way in a constructor (as well as being callable)?

I am trying to map `class`/`extend` to traditional constructor function/`[[Prototype]]` terminology.

So it is similar to the following?

```
function Bar() {}
function Foo() {
  Bar.call(this);
}
Foo.prototype = Object.create(Bar.prototype);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v5yf8e3u/1/

Comment: The most reliable source is the transpiled javascript code: See here :  goo.gl/AeJuCY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does `super` invoke the constructor function (aka class) `Bar`?

Yes

> Is `Bar.prototype` configured to be the prototype property of `Foo`?

No, an object with `Bar.prototype` on its `[[Prototype]]` is configured to be the `prototype` property of `Foo`.

> In `class` methods (and literal methods) `super` can be used as a reference to the instance of Bar (I think). Can it be used in the same way in a constructor (as well as being callable)?

No. And in methods, super refers to the `[[Prototype]]` of the `[[Prototype]]` AFAICT (i.e. the `prototype` property of `Bar`.

> So it is similar to the following?

Yes